# How to add screenshots in MS teams search based messaging extension app package?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a search based messaging extension for my org, i want to add screenshots for the app virtual tour in the manifest package... like its shown in the wikipedia app.[image]

My app looks something like this for now... How to add these screenshots?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add screenshots to your app description if you're submitting it to the store. It is available as part of the app submission process.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/prepare/submission-checklist